# WPF : How should I change the style of a button when his context id changed?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have two button styles as static resources. `BtnStyleOpen` and `BtnStyleClose`.
A button with `Name="V001"` and in .cs I Bound the context with an object
    `BtnV001.Content = content;` In content object there is a status property. 
I would like to change the style of the button when the status is changed.
My code is:

```
<Button x:Name="Btn001" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7"

                    Click="BtnV_Click" MouseRightButtonUp="BtnV_MouseRightButtonUp"

                    Content="{Binding Path=Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">


                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Content"  Value=1>
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BtnStyleOpen}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Content"  Value=0>
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource BtnStyleClose}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try bind it to the event that invoke the change. try use datatrigger.
something like this :

```
 <ToggleButton x:Name="togglebutton_Testing">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Textblock_Testing">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=togglebutton_Testing}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Open"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=togglebutton_Testing}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Close"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `IValueConverter` and apply it to the binding between `Button.Style` and `DataContext.Status`:

```
public class StatusToStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is Status status)
    {
      if (status == "open")
      {
        return (Style) Application.Current.FindResource("BtnStyleOpen");
      }

      if (status == "close")
      {
        return (Style) Application.Current.FindResource("BtnStyleClose");
      }
    }
    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

You the have to add an instance of the `IValueConverter?`to some resouce:

```
<Button.Resource>
  <StatusToStyleConverter x:Key"StatusToStyleConverter" />
<Button.Resource>
```

Then apply the `Style`:

```
<Button Style="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToStyleConverter}} />
```

As you didn't share details of your `Status` property type, you probably have to modify the condition evaluation in the converter.